# how to check for file count before sending files to sftp outbound adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I have a file:inbound-channel-adapter that scans for 6 files on the file system and then passes on the files to int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter for sending files to an sftp server. I want to implement a check that if all 6 files are available in the source directory, only then copy all of them to the sftp server. Nice to have will be to write some condition based on filenames to cancel sending to sftp server.

The only solution I could think of using an aggregator to count the files in the directory and then use a splitter to tranform them back to individual messages and then channel them to outbound-channel-adapter. But that approach seems to much for a simple case.

Is there a simple alternative. Basically it's about sending a group of messages if the group meets the criteria.

This is my config:

```
<bean id="fileFilterBean" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.SimplePatternFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg value="*.DAT"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="customerRelationChannelin" directory="file:${bwloan.outbound.sftp.ofsll.sharedFolder}" filter="fileFilterBean" >
    <int:poller cron="${bwloan.outbound.sftp.file.cron.expr}" max-messages-per-poll="50">
    </int:poller>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="customerRelationChannelin" output-channel="customerRelationChannelOut" ref="someHandler" />

<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter
            id="custRelFtpOutboundAdapter" channel="customerRelationChannelOut"
            remote-filename-generator-expression="payload.getName()"
            remote-directory="${myapp.outbound.sftp.remoteDirectory}"
            use-temporary-file-name="false"
            order="1" session-factory="custRelSftpSessionFactory"> 

</int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom FileListFilter that filters all files until 6 are present.